# how to create tab with system get property?

Tags: java

I know that I can find the new line of system with

```
     System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

does the line.separator will be always new line ?

How I can do the same for tab \t?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think there is an equivalent for tab, `\t` is a single character. while  the system property `line.separator` is a ([oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html))

> Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files

which mean it can be more than one character depending on the operation system the application running on. It can be `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.

Many text editing application offer to replace a tab key press by a sequence of spaces instead of the single character `\t`, from which users may define the length. This is handled by the application itself.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such standard property for <kbd>tab</kbd> you can rely on `'\t'` character

Answer (score 0):

"line.separator" - Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files.
Check this out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

`/t` is I believe software dependent, not system, so there is no such property. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getproperties.htm) you can check some other properties too.