# java - Writing to a file does not recognize \n and \t as escape characters

Tags: java, file

I have records in database that contains \n.

```
NAME            |  ROW  | COL  
-------------------------------
name            |   1   |   1  
address         |   1   |   2  
tel\n no        |   1   |   3  
employeed\n id  |   1   |   4
```

Then, I also save my delimiter , for text writing, in Database (\t)

```
DELIMITER |  FILENAME_LOCATIO
----------------------
\t        |  SAMPLETEXT
```

Then, when I already want to write those values(first table) to a text file, it prints like this..it does not recognized the escape characters, instead it printed as ordinary text

```
name\taddress\ttelno\n no\temployeed\n id
```

Text file should look like this..

```
name    address    telno
 no    employeed
 id
```

Here is the code im using..

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(config.get("FILENAME_LOCATION").toString(), true);
BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(fw);

List<Map<String, Object>> headers = sampleMapper.selectHeader();

for (Iterator<Map<String, Object>> iterator = headers.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) iterator.next();
    w.write(map.get("NAME").toString());    
    w.write(config.get("DELIMITER").toString()); // returns \t in String format
}

w.close();
```

Comment: What does `config.get("DELIMITER")` actually return?  What does `toString()` on that object actually return?

Comment: You need to store an actual "tab" in your db, not `\t`.

Comment: I have edited my question... thanks... that line return "\t"

Comment: @assylias how can I do that?? and how about the \n??

Comment: What OS is your code running on? The line delimiters depend on it.

Comment: If you are reading a string from source, escape characters will not be interpreted. eg. if you read "this\tthat" you will end up with "this\\tthat". You _could_ replace characters after you read the data.

Comment: I will be running this program both in windows and Linux..

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the OS you are running your application on, at least for the line delimiter.

```
try (BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\test.txt", false)))
{
    w.write("hello");
    w.write("\t");
    w.write("hello");
    w.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    w.write("world");
    w.write("\t");
    w.write("world");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code runs fine on my Windows, as the system property will provide you with the correct delimiter for the machine you're on (on Windows, it is `\r\n`).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715837/how-to-create-tab-with-system-get-property), `\t` should work, and it does for me. It might be that your config does not give you a tab, but `"\\t"`, which means a literal `\` and a `t`.  In that case, you could store the ascii char for tab in the database instead of `\t`.